# Não consigo mandar meus repositorios do git para o GitHub

Tags: git, github, mint

Eu fiz todo o processo do git em outra maquina com windows e funcionou tudo normal, quando vim para minha maquina com mint simplemente toda vez que chego na parte de dar git push eu recebo isso

> elend@Elend:~/magic/testeGitHub$ git push teste main Username for
> 'https://github.com': pl4cydo Password for
> 'https://pl4cydo@github.com':  remote: Support for password
> authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal
> access token instead. remote: Please see
> https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
> for more information. fatal: Authentication failed for
> 'https://github.com/pl4cydo/Teste.git/'

Faço de tudo, coloco minha senha e tudo mais, já fiz a chave ssh, já reinstalei já tentei outras pastas mas dai não sai.
alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

O GitHub não está mais aceitando senhas de contas ao autenticar operações do Git. Você precisa de um PAT(Personal Access Token).

Pra criar um Personal Access Token no Github você precisa ir na sua conta Github e vai em Settings => Developer Settings => Personal Access Token => Generate New Token => Preenche o formulário => clique em Generate token => Copie o token gerado.

Depois pra configurar no Linux

```
$ git config --global user.name "your_github_username"
$ git config --global user.email "your_github_email"
```

Uma vez que o GIT foi configurado, você pode acessar o Github

```
$ git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

Coloca o seu username e senha (ou pode usar o token que foi gerado)

Depois você pode usar a cache pra guardar o token

```
$ git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Mais informações aqui https://docs.github.com/pt/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token